# callback for facebook share button using addthis

Tags: facebook, addthis

I am using addThis for facebook share option.

```
<a class="addthis_button_preferred_1"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_preferred_2"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_preferred_3"></a>
```

When the user completes facebook sharing I need to do functionalities.

So guys please help me on how I can do a callback after successful sharing.

Comment: guys let me know if my question not clear

Answer (score 0):

AddThis provides a way to detect when a user clicks sharing:

http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/articles/381263-addthis-client-api#events

This doesn't guarantee that the user actually shared the page (there isn't really a way to do this across different networks without doing the share server side with an API).  This is the closest way to accomplish what you want.